# Chrome do not restrict ip address for webrtc now?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

At last month, I tested the trickle ICE at "https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/".
At that time, The Address showed like this "cc17a61e-dcb5-4ba9-bbbc-590a35450dd2.local". After I do run navigator.mediadevices.getMediaUser() at console, I can get address like this "70.30.XXX.XXX".

But now, I can get address like this "70.30.XXX.XXX" without any media permission. Is there any chrome policy change about this?

Comment: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() is a persistent permission in Chrome. You can revoke it in the settings